HTML audio with javascript: playback of playlist is not correct -> index 2 is always skipped
Need someone to help me understand, why index 2 of the playlist array that is passed to the audio element is skipped - no matter what. This is the console output:
0: /track01.mp3
1: /track02.mp3
2: /track03.mp3 // -> is logged but not played
3: /track01.mp3
4: undefined
(Note: It happens with whatever file is on index 2, so if I change the sequence of the files in the playlist array, still index 2 will be skipped.)
This is the code:
    let playlist = ["track01.mp3", "track02.mp3", "track03.mp3", "track01.mp3"]
    let song_index = 0
    playSong(playlist)
    
    console.log(playlist) // contains 4 files

    function playSong(playlist){
    console.log(`${song_index}: ${playlist[song_index]}`)
 
    audio_source.src = playlist[song_index]
    audio_source.load()
    audio_source.addEventListener("canplay", () => {
        audio_source.play()        
    })
    
    audio_source.addEventListener("ended", () => {
        if ((song_index) < playlist.length) {
            song_index++
            playSong(playlist)
        } else {
            song_index = 0
            playSong(playlist)
        }
    })
}

So whatever audio file is on index 2 of the array - it will not be played. The console.log logs index 2, but the audio player skips to index 3, without having played index 2.

Side note, you can simplify: if ((song_index) < playlist.length) { song_index++; playSong(playlist) } else { song_index = 0; playSong(playlist) } to -> song_index = (song_index + 1) % playlist.length; playSong(playlist)

That's good but unfortunately it doesn't solve the issue of index 2 being ignored by the audio element.

You have a sparse array, index 4 is logged as undefined. You can remove that undefined using .filter(). ex. playlist.filter(Boolean),

Doesn't solve the issue, however thanks for pointing out the sparse array thing, wasn't aware of that before

I think the issue  lies in the condition in your ended event listener because after  the song at index 2 finished playing, song_index is incremented to 3 and condition (song_index) < playlist.length evaluates to true because playlist.length is 4 hereby making a recursive call which results in playSong(playlist) being called again with song_index equal to 3.
Try and adjust the condition in your ended event listener to check if song_index is less than playlist.length - 1. This ensures that the index does not go out of bounds and correctly plays all songs in the playlist:

Thanks for the suggestion. Did so and with that at least the undefined is removed from the array (the sparse array thing). However issue remains and index 2 is skipped.

Event handlers:
node.addEventListener(event, callback) // method
// or
node.onevent = callback; // property
// or
<div onevent="callback()"> // inline attribute (not recommended)

are set and forget, they don't need to be re-registered or manually recalled during runtime. playSong() registers two "events" by .addEventListener() everytime when "ended" or "canplay" event is triggered. Since the audio object is already registered, nothing happens or something happens unexpectedly? Moreover, the function calls itself like a recursive function but with no real advantage.
Also, the playlist is a sparse array which is never good.
0: /track01.mp3
1: /track02.mp3
2: /track03.mp3 // -> is logged but not played
3: /track01.mp3
4: undefined    // this can only muck up things on each iteration

playlist.length isn't 4 it's actually 5 but undefined is usually ignored. So the index count is fluctuating and the middle index of 2 is lost in limbo. There can be many reasons why you would have a sparse array, but more importantly there's an easy way to fix one:
const denseArray = sparseArray.filter(Boolean);

In the example below there are two behaviors:

It properly plays the next MP3 after the previous one has ended. Once the playlist has reached it's end it'll start playing at the start.

If a user clicks the <table>, the MP3 that was clicked will play and the player will continue from that point.


Details are commented in the example.


/**
 * Audio Player
 */
// Always declare counters outside of functions
let index = 0;

// This will be filled with strings: path + list[index]
let playlist = [];

// This is the base URL to the MP3s
const path = "http://soundbible.com/mp3/";

// These are just MP3 titles
const name = ["Gong", "Applause", "Thunder", "Machine Gun", "Flatline"];

// MP3 files
const list = ["chinese-gong-daniel_simon.mp3", "Fake%20Applause-SoundBible.com-1541144825.mp3", "thunder_strike_1-Mike_Koenig-739781745.mp3", "Gun_war-MysteryMan229-1208990486.mp3", "Heart%20Rate%20Monitor%20Flatline-SoundBible.com-2063567528.mp3"];

// The Audio Object, it's a player without the <audio> element
const player = new Audio();

/**
 * DOM Building
 */
// HTML base
document.body.innerHTML = `
  <table>
    <thead>
      <caption>
        <a href="${path.slice(0, -4)}" target="_blank">
          ${path.slice(0, -4)}
        </a>${path.slice(-4)}
      </caption>
      <tr><th>#</th><th>Song</th><th>File</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>`;

// Reference the <table>
const table = document.querySelector("table");

/* For each string of name[] array render a <tr> to <table>
 * Interpolate data from arrays list[] and name[]
 * Fill the playlist[] array on every iteration as well
 */
name.forEach((n, i) => {
  table.innerHTML += `<tr>
     <td>${i}</td>
     <td>${n}</td>
     <td><div>${list[i]}</div></td>
  </tr>`;
  playlist.push(path + list[i]);
});

/**
 * Event Binding
 */
// Create an array of <tr>s and slice out the header <tr>
const tRows = Array.from(table.rows).slice(1);

// Callback function for clicking <table>
function clickRow(e) {
  // Remove ".active" from all <tr>
  tRows.forEach(r => r.classList.remove("active"));

  // If the user clicked a <td>...
  if (e.target.matches("td")) {

    // get the index position of that <td>'s <tr>...
    index = tRows.indexOf(e.target.parentElement);

    // add ".active" to that <tr>...
    e.target.parentElement.classList.add("active");

    // assign [src] for player determined by the new index...
    player.src = playlist[index];

    // and finally, play MP3
    player.play();
  } else {
    /* Otherwise, if the user clicked anywhere else on the
     * <table>, player will pause
     */
    player.pause();
  }
}

/* Bind <table> to "click" event and invoke callback function
 * clickRow() when "click" event is triggered
 */
table.onclick = clickRow;

// Callback function for "ended" event of the player
function nextSong(e) {
  // Incerment index
  index++;
  // Remove ".active" from all <tr>
  tRows.forEach(r => r.classList.remove("active"));

  // If index is equal to or exceeds the length of playlist (5)...
  if (index >= playlist.length) {
  
    // reset index to zer0
    index = 0;
  }

  // Add ".active" to current <tr>
  tRows[index].classList.add("active");
  // Assign [src] for player determined by the new index
  player.src = playlist[index];
  // play MP3
  player.play();
}

/* Bind player to the "ended" event and invoke callback function
 * nextSong() when "ended" event is triggered
 */
player.onended = nextSong;
:root {
  font: 5vmin/1 "Segoe UI";
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

caption {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

tr th:nth-of-type(n+2) {
  text-align: left;
}

tr td:first-of-type {
  text-align: center
}

th {
  padding-bottom: 0.25rem
}

td {
  border: 3px black inset;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
}

th:first-of-type {
  width: 10%
}

th:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 30%
}

th:last-of-type {
  width: 60%;
}

td div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 2.25rem;
}

tr:hover td {
  border-bottom-color: red;
  color: red;
}

.active td,
.active:hover td {
  color: white;
  background: red;
}




Thanks for the event handler info, indeed I'm not very familiar with that stuff. You're code works well (wish mine did :D). Will have to dive into all that very carefully.

You're welcome, but more importantly, you need to have a dense array in order to process index 2. Try filtering that array as shown in the third code block above or backtrack and figure out why that array has an undefined at index 4. If you actually know the exact MP3 files to play, try creating an array literal as a test (ex. verbatim: let playlist = ["track1.mp3",  "track2.mp3", "track3.mp3"];), and don't have any duplicates like in the OP (a "track1.mp3" at both ends just makes it harder to discern by ear). Also... (continue to next comment)

..., remove the old declaration: var playlist, let playlist, or const playlist.  Next, remove any references outside of playSong(). What I mean by "remove" is to comment it instead of deleting the text (ex. // let playlist = [...] or /* let playlist = [...] */). I would've added this to the answer, but I don't think it'll help future readers much.

I suspect you're running into issues of canplay firing or not firing when you don't expect.  Remember, this event can fire multiple times for the same files, and you're actually using the same event handling even after switching files.
There's no need for all this.  You can simplify your code by getting rid of .load() and the canplay handler, and just calling .play().  It's the behavior you're looking for.
audio_source.src = playlist[song_index];
audio_source.play();


Did so but unfortunately the issue persists (index 2 is skipped). Plus at some point the console shows this warning:
"Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a new load request. "
